# How to multiply contents from different tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL query to list all the warehouses and their total sales. Here, given a product, the total sale of the product is calculated by the sold quantity of the product and its unit price. The list must be ordered by the total sales in the descending. [Reminder: one product_ID may link to more than one warehouses in the provided data. You can ignore this and just count the sale of the product to all its linked to warehouse. ]

```
CREATE TABLE warehouses
  (
    warehouse_id NUMBER 
                 GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 10 
                 PRIMARY KEY,
    warehouse_name VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
    location_id    NUMBER( 12, 0 ), -- fk
    CONSTRAINT fk_warehouses_locations 
      FOREIGN KEY( location_id )
      REFERENCES locations( location_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
-- employees
CREATE TABLE employees
  (
    employee_id NUMBER 
                GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 108 
                PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    phone      VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    hire_date  DATE NOT NULL          ,
    manager_id NUMBER( 12, 0 )        , -- fk
    job_title  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_employees_manager 
        FOREIGN KEY( manager_id )
        REFERENCES employees( employee_id )
        ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
-- product category
CREATE TABLE product_categories
  (
    category_id NUMBER 
                GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 6 
                PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR2( 255 ) NOT NULL
  );

-- products table
CREATE TABLE products
  (
    product_id NUMBER 
               GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 289 
               PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name  VARCHAR2( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    description   VARCHAR2( 2000 )        ,
    standard_cost NUMBER( 9, 2 )          ,
    list_price    NUMBER( 9, 2 )          ,
    category_id   NUMBER NOT NULL         ,
    CONSTRAINT fk_products_categories 
      FOREIGN KEY( category_id )
      REFERENCES product_categories( category_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
CREATE TABLE orders
  (
    order_id NUMBER 
             GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 106 
             PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id NUMBER( 6, 0 ) NOT NULL, -- fk
    status      VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
    salesman_id NUMBER( 6, 0 )         , -- fk
    order_date  DATE NOT NULL          ,
    CONSTRAINT fk_orders_customers 
      FOREIGN KEY( customer_id )
      REFERENCES customers( customer_id )
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_orders_employees 
      FOREIGN KEY( salesman_id )
      REFERENCES employees( employee_id ) 
      ON DELETE SET NULL
  );
-- order items
CREATE TABLE order_items
  (
    order_id   NUMBER( 12, 0 )                                , -- fk
    item_id    NUMBER( 12, 0 )                                ,
    product_id NUMBER( 12, 0 ) NOT NULL                       , -- fk
    quantity   NUMBER( 8, 2 ) NOT NULL                        ,
    unit_price NUMBER( 8, 2 ) NOT NULL                        ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_order_items 
      PRIMARY KEY( order_id, item_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_items_products 
      FOREIGN KEY( product_id )
      REFERENCES products( product_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_order_items_orders 
      FOREIGN KEY( order_id )
      REFERENCES orders( order_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
-- inventories
CREATE TABLE inventories
  (
    product_id   NUMBER( 12, 0 )        , -- fk
    warehouse_id NUMBER( 12, 0 )        , -- fk
    quantity     NUMBER( 8, 0 ) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_inventories 
      PRIMARY KEY( product_id, warehouse_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_inventories_products 
      FOREIGN KEY( product_id )
      REFERENCES products( product_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_inventories_warehouses 
      FOREIGN KEY( warehouse_id )
      REFERENCES warehouses( warehouse_id ) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

Comment: hello Zaid, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried but it was senseless.

Comment: hint: join the tables that you need the data from and use an aggregate function. If you post what you have tried then I can guide you in the right direction.